# imap_open() crashes Apache

Tags: php, apache, imap

Running Wamp 2.0 on Windows 7 64-bit with Apache 2.2.17 and PHP 5.3.4

I call imap_open() to connect to Gmail (imap.googlemail.com on port 993)

```
$server_spec = "{imap.googlemail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$mbox = imap_open ($server_spec, $username, $password);
```

But the webpage says the Connection was reset. I have no errors appearing in my logs.

But if I check Windows event viewer I see:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.2.17.0, time stamp: 0x4cc419ce
Faulting module name: php_imap.dll, version: 5.3.4.0, time stamp: 0x4d090506
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x000000000004ac04
Faulting process id: 0x3420
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc98a7507af588
Faulting application path: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.17\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\ext\php_imap.dll
Report Id: 9585a82f-049a-11e1-a83a-180373772b48
```

Googling the error hasn't come up with much, I've manually uncommented the php.ini file for php_imap. I also have enabled mod_ssl.

Have I forgotten something basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an "answer" technically - but downloading the latest Wamp package (apache 2.2.21 + php 5.3.8) fixes the issue